# What is the difference between map[string][]string and map[string]string?

Tags: dictionary, go

I noticed in the **[Go docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values)** this definition was included:

```
type Values map[string][]string
```

I thought it was a mistake, but then I tried this code and it compiles (<kbd>[Playground](http://play.golang.org/)</kbd>):

package main

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    type MyType map[string][]string

    foobar := make(MyType)

    fmt.Println(foobar)
}
```

Is it functionally equivalent to `map[string]string`, or is there some difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are different. One is a map of strings to a slice of strings, vs a map of strings to a single string

The `[]` in `[]string` denotes a slice

http://play.golang.org/p/nv7wSWW0F7

Comment: In Go they are [Slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), not the same as [Arrays](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types).

Answer (score 1):

One is a map of string slices while the other is a map of strings. One structure has a single dimension, the `map[string][]string` has two. At every key `k` you'll have items `0-n` in the slice. So access requires another level of direction like `fmt.Println(myInts[k][0])` as apposed to `fmt.Println(myInts[k])`. Put data in it and the difference will be more apparent.